# Неправильно показывает текущий месяц

Tags: java, android

Здраствуйте!Мне нужно получить текущую дату и время.Все отображается корректно ,кроме месяца:показывает 11-й месяц.

```
 java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    String sDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "."
            + c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            + "." + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            + " в " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    tv.setText(sDate);
```

Comment: Исчисление месяцев в Calendar начинается с 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что, январь начинается с 0, соответственно декабрь - 11-й месяц.
Если хотите получить именно 12 вместо 11, то можно написать так)

```
c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

Вот еще вариант, только вместо 12 возвращает сокращенный вариант месяца "дек",

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfMM = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
sdfMM.format(c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

И чтобы получить "декабрь"

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfMMM = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
sdfMMM.format(c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```